# PHP execution in a hidden way

Tags: php, html, json

Ok , Now I have a php code at http://www.anhatweb.tk/web/auth/create to create a new user ....
What I do is I send my data using POST to add into MySQL database and then send a mail to user for account verification.....since I am using a free website to host my website, the SMTP server is slow and sometimes takes very very large time to send mail making the page slow to load for the user.
What I want to do is to upload data into database then send mail in background without letting user experience the slow sending......
My mail code is simple...just basic PHP
Any other methods such as JSON,Jquery etc etc are appreciated but PHP is preferred
 **in short:**  I want to run php code in background without making server send any success/failure response to the user to the same page! Just run and redirect without the slow loading

Comment: You could do the mailings with a CRON every hour, I guess. Why is the mailing slow? I'd look at that.

Comment: I don't know anything about a cronjob ...can u please tell me how to execute a script that is in php format kept at www/ABC/script.php with a cronjob....help very much appreciated.....,.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push email to queue. And email workers listen this queue and when mail exist, send it to user. This mechanism used by framework Laravel. Queues and workers may have many implementations. For example queue is sql database, and worker is cronjobed script which execute every seconds and checks db

Comment: But can u please tell me the format of writing a cronjob to execute a script kept at www/ABC/script.php after every say 5 minutes.....please write the full format help appreciated

Comment: And one thing more ...since I am already using CodeIgniter as framework...I can't use Laravel

Comment: run in shell command `cronjob -e` from user who must run this script. In common case, you need to paste new line with next content: `*/5 * * * * php -f www/ABC/script.php` But in some cases it may will be different